# How to understand long-range propagate without decay in time and space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, greens-functions, propagator

Assume there is a Green function:
$$G=\frac{1}{(p^2+r)-\sum-\omega^2}$$
where $\sum$ is self-energy. We know that if the self-energy vanishes, the quasi-particle is well-define, and it can propagate all the time without decay, i.e. lifetime is infinite. However, we also know that when $r>0$, the quasiparticle can only propagate in short-range, and decay in the correlation length $\xi\sim r^{-1/2}$.Only when $r=0$, such particle become massless and can propagate over long range, e.g. phonon.  What I am confused about is that for particles without self-energy, it has an infinite lifetime, why can't it still propagate long distances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you are missing is relativity. A stable particle *can* propagate long distances - *as long as it has enough time to do so without breaking the speed-of-light barrier*.

The lifetime of a particle is proportional to $\mathrm{Im}\left[ \Sigma\left(-m^2 \right) \right]$, where $m$ is its mass, so it isn't actually necessary for the self-energy to completely vanish in order for the particle to be stable and have infinite lifetime; it's only necessary that $\Sigma(-m^2)$ be purely real. Nevertheless, for simplicity let's consider the simplest possible case of a stable particle - a free scalar field, where the self-energy does indeed vanish and
$$G({\bf p}, \omega) = \frac{1}{{\bf p}^2 - \omega^2 + m^2 }$$
(where my $m^2$ is your $r$).

Remember that the (real-space) propagator $G(x)$ is always a Lorentz-invariant function that only depends on the spacetime interval $s = x \cdot x$ of the argument $x$. For timelike $x$, the propagator is a Hankel function $-H(-s)/s = H(\tau^2)/\tau^2$, where $\tau$ is the proper time (I'm dropping lots of constants). For large $\tau$, this goes as $e^{i \tau^2}/\tau$, so the propagator decays very slowly (as a power law), which makes sense for a stable particle. For spacelike $x$, the propagator is a modified Bessel function $K_1(r)/r$ that decays rapidly (exponentially) as $e^{-r}/r^{3/2}$ for large $r$, where $r$ is the *proper* distance (not the coordinate distance).

So the point is that the particle can indeed propagate long distances, as long as it *stays inside the light cone* and has enough time to propagate over there "slower than the speed of light". What it can't do (except with vanishingly small probability) is propagate over large *spacelike* distances, as this would require "moving" faster than light.